# WebSocket Communication: communication between javascript and java class

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, bytebuffer, arraybuffer

My requirement is as below

**Step 1**

1. Establish WebSocket communication --> Done.
2. Send Data from client to Server --> Done
3. Receive Data from Server to client --> Done

**Step 2**

1. Establish WebSocket communication --> Done
2. Send String Data from client [jsp/javascript] to Server
3. String --> ArrayBuffer on javascript --> Done
4. Receive data on @ServerEndpoint java class in Bytebuffer --> Done
5. How to send back the same data to browser --> ??
6. How to convert the data to String --> ??

---

**Java class**

```
 @ServerEndpoint("/testwebsocket")
 public class WebSocketTest {

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(ByteBuffer bytedata, Session session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //session.getBasicRemote().sendText("replay from server for :" + bytedata);

    System.out.println("echoBinary: " + bytedata);
    String v = new String(bytedata.array(), "UTF-8");
    for (byte b : bytedata.array()) {
        System.out.print(b);
    }
    session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(bytedata);
}
```

**Javascript code for Receive**

```
function onMessage(event) {


if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer){

    alert("onMessage if ");
    var strReceived = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(event.data));
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<br />' + 'receieved' + event;
}
else
{
    alert("onMessage else ");
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<br />' + event.data;
}   }
```

**Javascript code for sending**

```
//sending arraybuffer
function bytedata() {

//alert('I am in bytedata');
var str = document.getElementById('bytedataTextFeild').value;
var arrayByte = str2ab(str);
websocket.send(arrayByte);
return false;
}

//creating arraybuffer from string
function str2ab(str) {
//alert('I am in str2ab ' + str);  
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<br />'
            + str.charCodeAt(i);
}
return buf;

}
```

**on Browser**

jsp textbox String passed --> *Hello*

**Data Sent**

72
101
108
108
111

**Data Received**

[object Blob] --> *I want this as "Hello"*

Comment: What errors do you have in the console?

Comment: Please be more specific.  You expect the browser to receive a message from the server and what happens instead?  Is onMessage called?  Is it not the type of data you were expecting?

Comment: In JavaScript, I think it should be `'<br />' + 'receieved' + strReceived;` instead of `'<br />' + 'receieved' + event;`